Writing Kullback–Leibler divergence in terms of the score function
Assume we have two density functions $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$  for $x\in R^d$.
I would find a connection between Kullback–Leibler divergence between two densities in terms of the difference between the gradient of the log densities: $\nabla_{x} \log p(x)$ and $\nabla_{x} \log p'(x)$.
Something like
$$\int p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{p'(x)}dx\le \frac{1}{2}E_{x}||\nabla_{x} \log p(x)-\nabla_{x} \log p'(x)||_2^2.$$
Can anyone help me please. I have already tried starting the definition of the KL and then integrating by part, but I stuck at some points then.

sotty but the left hand part is an integration over the whole support of $X$, where the right hand part is a distance of the score function for a specific point $x$

lol... *sorry ...

Ahh sorry, an expectation was missed. Thanks, I have edited that.

For some families of distributions, there is a relationship between the two.
The result is not from this paper, but they give the clearest exposition: Otto, Villani, 2000, Generalization of an Inequality by Talagrand and Links with the Logarithmic Sobolev Inequality.
The quantity you are interested in, they define as the relative Fisher information in equation 8.
In definition 1, they give the caracterization of a measure $q$ satisyfing a logarithmic sobolev inequality with constant $\rho$ as satisfying the inequality you seek with constant $\rho$
$$
KL(p, q) \leq \frac{1}{2\rho} I(p,q)
$$
The key ingredient we now need is: what families are $LSI(\rho)$. That's stated in theorem 2, due Bakry and Emery: strongly log-concave distributions are $LSI(\rho)$.

Many thanks for the help. Sounds great. I also found something that looks Kinda related but not sure about the details. In this work https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.01916 (Page 11), they claim ''If Novikov’s conditions are satisfied, Girsanov’s Theorem then applies to bound the KL divergence in terms of the squared difference of the drift
terms between the processes.''

I haven't read this paper but, in general, I'd be extremely dubious about any mathematical claims made in a machine-learning paper, unless it's published in an absolutely top-tier journal (and not in the proceedings of a conference).

Sure Thank you.

I don't think so.
First, you can make very small changes to $p$ and $p'$ that result in small changes to the KL-divergence but arbitrarily large changes to $\nabla_x p(x)$ (ie, put little high-frequency wiggles on the density)
Second, the KL-divergence is related to the Fisher information. If you interpolate a smooth parametric family $p(x,\theta)$ so that $p(x,\theta_0)=p(x)$ and $p(x,\theta_1)=p'(x)$ then the derivative wrt $\theta$ of the KL divergence is the Fisher information. That's similar to what you have, but suggests that you need gradients along a path between the two densities, not gradients with respect to $x$.
The linked document constructs the KL-divergence as an integral of the Fisher information along a geodesic path between two densities.

Hey Thomas. There is actually a strong link between the two quantities but it's only valid on some specific families. see my answer below

Interesting! If you have enough smoothness then i suppose the pathologies can't happen
